# SDL bit depth conversion

Tags: sdl, sdl-2

I'm beating my way through a 1.2->2.0 conversion, one problem at a time. So far I have sound, interaction and a screen that shows... well, something.

I'm sure the problem is due to bit depth and/or formats. The original code used 8-bit *indexed* SPR files for the sprites, loaded them into a series of `uint8 *buffu`, and then blitted them to the display's Surface.

I have ported this, following the guide and significant trial-and-error (lots of modes and switches simply don't work on my machine), by creating a Texture and a Surface, letting the old code blit into the Surface, and then do this...

```
SDL_UpdateTexture(sdltxtr, NULL, sdlsurf->pixels, 640 * sizeof (uint8));
SDL_RenderClear(sdlrend);
SDL_RenderCopy(sdlrend, sdltxtr, NULL, NULL);
SDL_RenderPresent(sdlrend);
```

The result is a screen with stuff, but it's all misaligned. I assume that is because the Surface and Texture have different bit depths and formats than the sprites...

```
sdltxtr = SDL_CreateTexture(sdlrend,
                            SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888,
                            SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING,
                            640, 480);
sdlsurf = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0, 640, 480, 8, 0,0,0,0);
```

I've tried various settings from the documentation to try to get a surface or texture that's 8-bit indexed, but all of the flags cause the Surface or Texture to be empty.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your surface always getting updated? Or is it a sprite that does not change over time?

Comment: The Surface is updated all the time, as new bitmaps are blitted into it. That said, you can see the problem as soon as the game starts, a period when all it does is load a few bitmaps into the Surface and sits there waiting for input. I can see that the bitmaps ARE loading into the Surface/Texture, but they are "wrong".

Answer (score 1):

You mention *indexed* 8-bit graphics. Assuming that indexed means *palettized*, you can't simply use the pixel buffer, since this is just a list of entries to the associated color palette of the SDL_Surface.

That being said, you need to create a buffer that actually holds the correct ARGB values from the palette, but not the index values associated with the pixel buffer.

You could use SDL_ConvertSurfaceFormat() to convert your 8-bit palettized surface to a 32-bit ARGB surface and place its buffer into the SDL_Texture. You also can create an own 32-bit ARGB buffer and do the conversion yourself by looking up the correct palette codes (the first option will be easier in most cases, though).

Before you are converting the 8-bit SDL_Surface to a 32-bit one, you *should* associate a valid palette with it (SDL_SurfaceSetPalette()).